# Uses of RJ11 Port Other Than as A Landline

Tags: networking, phone, rj-11

I have a very old laptop I use as a home server and it has an RJ11 port. Apart from calling through and from with this connection as a landline, are there any other practical uses for this today?

Comment: That port will have special hardware behind it in your laptop. If it is a 56k modem then you will be limited to the things a 56k modem can do: being a modem and (maybe) making phone calls.

Comment: @Mokubai Cool, I'll look into it. I might use it to record my phone conversations.

Answer (score 2):

That RJ-11 port almost certainly is just a POTS modem (Plain Old Telephone Service; analog dial-up voice landline modem).

Without a real telephone landline, and perhaps even without a simulator box that provides dial tone and ring voltage and DTMF touchtone decoding, you could probably hook it directly to another POTS modem via a telephone line cord (RJ-11 cord) and make a 33.6 kilobit per second (or less) connection over it, if you have a good serial comms app/tool and know your Hayes AT command set.

Comment: As @Spiff states, you can set up a 56 kB "network"... and have done so back in he days of the Atari 800XL and Apple IIe. A ring tone wasn't required, and a 24 VDC wallwart with 600 ohm resistor provided bias (actually, 14 kbS, for those modems).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Hah! I'm a bit too young for those days, but I might want to try that out sometime.

Answer (score 2):

RJ-11 jacks have one other use: Receiving and transmitting faxes.

Yes, faxing is [19th Century tech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax#Wire_transmission), but many doctors' offices and real estate firms still rely on it.  Note: Faxing from a PC works best over a [Plain Old Telephone Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service) ('POTS') line, will interfere with DSL service, and fails often if you your phone service is delivered over a [digital carrier line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_system).